# Gmail icon on beta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase

In the "help us grow this site" box on the beta SE sites, there are six icons for ways to advertise the site through social media.  Five of them use company icons to connect to that company - facebook, twitter, delicious, stumbleupon and linkedin.  But the first icon is a gmail icon, used to represent email in general.

I don't think that's a good generic representative of email - I'd prefer something like the envelope icon we have at the left of our names in the top bar.  Certainly, when I clicked it, I expected to get gmail, though my default mailto handler is actually Outlook - instead I got Outlook and was momentarily confused.

I also suspect that Google might get annoyed about it in trademark terms, but really, "one of those things is not like the others" is a bigger concern for me.

Comment: for me, email and gmail are synonym.

Comment: @ngu, which makes the button more confusing.

Comment: @Ngu, it's not about whether e-mail = Gmail for _anyone_, it's about whether e-mail = Gmail for _everyone_. And the answer is clearly that it's not.

Comment: @Popular Demand, I think those who're *still* not using Gmail doesn't deserve to use SO and SEs. Call me extremist, but I believe that it's such a huge loss if one doesn't know how to use the best tools at hand.

Comment: @Ngu, you have a point; we certainly wouldn't want `John.Smith@microsoft.com` or `Jane.Doe@oracle.com` on SO. Freakin' Outlook users, man.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the color of the envelope to something else than red would probably be sufficient to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just making it an envelope without the gmail-M would work even better.